# Decomposiom of the representation of $SU(N)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $T$ be the "fundamental" representation (I mean the one in which the matrices representing
the group elements are simply themselves) of $SU(N)$ group. I have

\begin{pmatrix}
 SU(N-1)& 0\\ 
 0& 1 
\end{pmatrix}

where $SU(N-1)$ is subgroup of $SU(N)$.

Can I decompose representation $T$ of $SU(N)$ to irreducible representations of $SU(N-1)$? If yes, can you explain me how to do it?

Comment: You can definitely decompose $T$ by restrcting to $SU(n-1)$. In this case, the answer is not too hard. If the basis you've chosen is $v_{1}, \ldots, v_{n}$, then the first $n-1$ vectors generate the fundamental representation of $SU(n-1)$ and the last vector spans a trivial representation.